# What serialization framework does Apache Thrift use?

Tags: serialization, thrift, kryo, thrift-protocol

What serialization framework does Facebook's Apache Thrift use in a Java environment? Java built-in serialization or Kryo, or something else?

### EDIT:

I see that Thrift has a class called `TSerializer` which seems to implement `TBase` which implements `java.io.serialializable`. I may not get the order right.

Comment: Thrift is an **cross-platform**, **cross-language**  RPC and **serialization** framework. So what does that tell us?

Comment: Implements it's own. Possibly extending java's `Serializable` which is very slow; much slower than Kryo.

Answer (score 1):

Thrift uses its own mechanisms, in Thrift-speak these are called [Transport](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/transport/TTransport.java;hb=HEAD). This is the case across all languages to ensure interoperatbility. One of these Transports is the [`TFileTransport`](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/transport/TFileTransport.java;hb=HEAD), and another, popular one is [`TSocket`](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/transport/TSocket.java;hb=HEAD).

If you look at the code, you will find that thrird-party libraries are in general used very sparsely, for several reasons. Available built-in mechanisms are also not used, because these are typically a language specific thing and thus not portable across languages.

Last not least one of the key features of Thrift is its openness. Anyone can easily write his or her own Transport or Protocol implementations and plug them into the system. Some of them can be found in the [`/contrib`](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=tree;f=contrib;hb=HEAD) folder.

> Let's say the target environment was Java. What serialization method would it implement -- Java's native serialization? I see that Thrift has a class called TSerializer [...]

You just instantiate the [`TSerializer`](http://people.apache.org/~thejas/thrift-0.9/javadoc/org/apache/thrift/TSerializer.html) and use it. If you have special requirements regarding the protocol, use the alternative CTOR to e.g. pass amn instance of `TJSONProtocolFactory` or whatever else you need. By default the serializer assumes `TBinaryProtocol`.

Then you simply call

```
TSerializer  serializer = new TSerializer();
TBytes data = serializer.serialize( myThriftObject);
```

and do whatever you want with `data`.

Comment: Let's say the target environment was Java. What serialization method would it implement -- Java's native serialization?